# Backbone - Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Below gives me an error "**Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined**" as it cannot find jquery.

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: "/static/javascript",
  paths: {
    jquery: "vendor/jquery",
    underscore: "vendor/underscore"
  },
  shim: {
    underscore: {
      exports: "_"
    }
} });
require(["underscore","jquery"],function(un){


    console.log("jQuery version: ", $.fn.jquery);
    console.log("underscore identity call: ", _.identity(5));
  console.log("underscore identity call: ", un.identity(5));
});
```

However if I change the code to the following:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: "vendor/jquery",
    underscore: "vendor/underscore"
  },
  shim: {
    underscore: {
      exports: "_"
    }
} });
require(["underscore","vendor/jquery"],function(un){


    console.log("jQuery version: ", $.fn.jquery);
    console.log("underscore identity call: ", _.identity(5));
  console.log("underscore identity call: ", un.identity(5));
});
```

**It now works**. The path is the same if you look. Why does my system have such issues with baseURL? whats wrong with the first code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare here the global  you will use

```
require(["underscore","jquery"],function(un, $ /* <- insert here */){

console.log("jQuery version: ", $.fn.jquery); // <- so here $ exists, $.fn too
```

in the second example it works because **I suppose** that jQuery, Backbone, Underscore registers themselves using the global functions $, _, etc.., even when used with RequireJS shims.